# POST Method for connecting Supabase and Draftbit not working

Tags: react-native, supabase, supabase-database, supabase-js

I have tried to create a new record in Draftbit by following the instructions in this Draftbit blog https://draftbit.com/blog/how-to-create-a-native-mobile-app-for-your-supabase-back-end but it has not worked. I used Groceries as my path and used POST but I get a 400 error message when I test the create a new record endpoint. All the previous steps (GET) in the blog have worked but not sure why the create a new record with POST is not working. I'm guessing I am not doing something right on the Supabase side of things but I am completely dumbfounded on what the issue could be since all the previous sections have worked out thus far. Has anyone else had this issue? I am new to coding and don't have prior experience so any helpful suggestions would be highly appreciated.